# Segmentation fault after user input

Tags: c, input, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

Below I have included my full code to a program I am working on. It should allow the user to enter input into the program until they enter a '.' in the first name input. I am getting segmentation faults after going through input once, and once I go to enter input into the struct a second time it faults me. I am also supposed to dynamically allocate the struct so that the user can enter in input as many times as they want, but to test I set it to 10 to see if the program would work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    int recordCount;
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    char *id;
    char *email;
};

int main()
{
    struct student *aPtr;

    aPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct student)*10);
    //aPtr = (struct student*) malloc(10 * sizeof(struct student));
    aPtr->firstName = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    aPtr->lastName = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    aPtr->id = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    aPtr->email = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("First Name: ");
        scanf("%s", (aPtr + i)->firstName);
        if ((aPtr + i)->firstName[0] == '.') {
            break;
        }

        printf("Last Name: ");
        scanf("%s", (aPtr + i)->lastName);

        printf("ID#: ");
        scanf("%s", (aPtr + i)->id);

        printf("Email: ");
        scanf("%s", (aPtr + i)->email);


        printf("\n");
        aPtr->recordCount++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < aPtr->recordCount; ++i) {
        printf("%s, %s, %s, %s",(aPtr + i)->id, (aPtr + i)->firstName, (aPtr + i)->lastName, (aPtr + i)->email);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your program under a debugger.

Comment: You only initialized the fields of `aPtr[0]`, but you’re trying to use the fields of 10 of them.

Comment: Look up how to use pointers.

Comment: I'd suggest declaring char firstName[50] rather than char *firstName. Just dynamically allocate a new struct Student each time you need one, but don't do it for the various struct members. And keep track of all the students you allocate, in an array or linked list. Finally, free the entire list before you exit main.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](http://prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: My formatting on the original code is fine, I just don't really know how to use stack overflow so it kinda messed everything up.

Comment: @JsmileyJ Well, if you plan to use it, you might want to figure it out. https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet

Comment: When investigating something like this, it really helps to work with a completely stripped-down version of your code - a [mcve].  Instead of allocating 10 `student`s, just try to populate a single one, with just one or two of its fields.  Build up from there until your error appears and then solve it.  That eliminates all the working parts from suspicion.

Comment: the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression from the parameter to `malloc()`.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `aPtr->firstName = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);`.   the `aPtr` points to an array of struct student, so individual fields of one instance of the struct should be accessed via: `aPtr[i]->firstName`   Although, I strongly suggest replacing those pointer fields within the struct with something like: `char firstName[50];`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field so the user cannot overrun the input field.  Such overrun results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: only the first instance of the field `record count` is being used.  Strongly suggest removing that field from the `struct student`.

Answer (score 0):

Use gdb debugger to debug your code, you can find it yourself. 
In case you are new to debugging, follow this link to learn more about it. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/index.htm

In this code, I think you are using the pointer incorrectly in this line:

```
aPtr + i)->firstName[0] == '.'
```

rectify it, look up for the proper use of pointers.

Note: you can make your code more easy by using char firstname[50], lastname[50],.....etc. With use of it, you can get rid of segmentation fault very easily.

Hope it helps! Thank You.